# No connection configured

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jooq

how i can configure connection for fix this bug? I use MySQL and jdbc.

```
public static void saveCallLink(String oktell_login, String link)
        throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = DBConnection.getDataSource().getConnection();
    DSL.using(conn)
            .insertInto(CALLS)
            .columns(CALLS.USER_ID, CALLS.CALL_LINK)
            .values(
                    DSL.select(USERS.ID)
                            .from(USERS)
                            .where(USERS.OKTELL_LOGIN.equal(oktell_login))
                            .fetchOne().value1()
                    , link
            ).execute();
    conn.close();
}
```

Sorry, log was added.

org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute query. No Connection configured
    org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:316)
    org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:365)
    org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:352)
    org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchOne(AbstractResultQuery.java:517)
    org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchOne(SelectImpl.java:2868)
    ru.avito.model.CallModel.saveCallLink(CallModel.java:33)
    ru.avito.web.OktellListener.saveCallRecord(OktellListener.java:31)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```java
DSL.using(conn)
   .insertInto(CALLS)
   .columns(CALLS.USER_ID, CALLS.CALL_LINK)
   .values(
       DSL.select(USERS.ID)
          .from(USERS)
          .where(USERS.OKTELL_LOGIN.equal(oktell_login))
          .fetchOne().value1() // This query cannot be executed
       , link
   ).execute();
```

The query you ran in the middle of your `INSERT` statement cannot be executed because it has no `Configuration` (context) attached to it. As a general rule of thumb, always remember:

- `DSLContext` creates queries that are "attached" to the `DSLContext.configuration()`, and thus can be executed directly
- `DSL` creates queries that are "unattached", and thus cannot be executed, only embedded in other queries

There are two solutions:

#### 1. Attach the nested select

```java
DSL.using(conn)
   .insertInto(CALLS)
   .columns(CALLS.USER_ID, CALLS.CALL_LINK)
   .values(
       DSL.using(conn) // Use DSLContext, not DSL here
          .select(USERS.ID)
          .from(USERS)
          .where(USERS.OKTELL_LOGIN.equal(oktell_login))
          .fetchOne().value1()
       , link
   ).execute();
```

Note though, that this will run two separate queries from the client, which is probably not what you really want. You want:

#### 2. Nest your `SELECT` in the `INSERT` statement

```java
DSL.using(conn)
   .insertInto(CALLS)
   .columns(CALLS.USER_ID, CALLS.CALL_LINK)
   .values(
       DSL.field(
           DSL.select(USERS.ID)
              .from(USERS)
              .where(USERS.OKTELL_LOGIN.equal(oktell_login))
       )
       , link
   ).execute();
```

This is now the same as the following single SQL query:

```sql
INSERT INTO calls (user_id, call_link)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM users WHERE oktell_login = :oktell_login), :link)
```